# Is it possible to keep formatting when pasting rich text from a browser into inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

When I paste text into inkscape from Firefox and Chromium, the formatting (bold, italics, etc) is removed. Is there any setting in inkcape that would allow to keep the formatting intact when pasting rich text?

Answer (score 1):

There's no option to do this.

The best workaround for large amounts of text is to use a pdf printer (e.g. CutePDF on Windows) and then load the pdf into inkscape.  For smaller snippets, pasting into your favourite pdf-exporting word processor saving as PDF and opening in inkscape can work.  This works better with Libreoffice than MS Word, as the characters are individually placed in the PDF from Word, and editing is a pain, even though it looks good.