# How to keep HTML formatting when copy text to Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, text, html

I have a text with headings, lists, hyperlinks in my editors, and I want to preserve them when copy to Inkscape. How can I do that?

Comment: This isn't possible as far as I'm aware.  There's another question here regarding copying and pasting text with formatting, and one workaround metioned [Is it possible to keep formatting when pasting rich tetext from a browser into Inkscape](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/78340/is-it-possible-to-keep-formatting-when-pasting-rich-text-from-a-browser-into-ink)

Comment: Do you have any idea on why this is not possible?

Comment: Probably because Inkscape isn't really designed to be page layout software, and it only has pretty basic text handling capabilities.  You probably want something like Scribus or InDesign.